# Is it possible to give Pascal more than one scalop?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

I've been trying to collect the mermaid set in ACNH, but Pascal keeps giving me pearls instead. As far as I'm aware of, he only asks for one scalop a day. Is it possible to give him a scalop (that he didn't ask for after I caught it) so I can get the mermaid set even quicker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The only way to summon pascal is for him to appear after grabbing a scallop.

As you've observed, this limits you to once / day.

**Perseverance, friend!**

Mermaids come to those who wait!

Comment: Hey, i hate to revive an old question, but do you know exactly my probability of getting said DIY recipes? Im just really curious

Comment: I do not, though I know there are several prominent Twitter users (Ninji, I believe?) who have de-compiled the game's source code and code answer affirmatively.